# Is it possible to host a Blazor Server on AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, blazor, blazor-server-side

I've recently finished the prototype for my blazor server app and I'd like to put it on a server (or somewhere where it can be open 24/7). I'm quite new this whole enviroment but i've heard that aws is the easiest (and cheapest since its free) way to host a server. I've noticed that a lot of tutorials and guides focus on Blazor WebAssemblies but none seem to mention Blazor Server Apps.

Most of them also seem to mention AWS Amplify which seems pretty simple to setup, but after trying to configure it to a Blazor Server app build nothing came out of it. The build was successfull tho.

Is it possible to host a Blazor Server App via AWS? In a way that i can easly publish new versions if needed?

Comment: Be careful about being sucked in by the AWS "free" tier. https://www.lastweekinaws.com/blog/is-the-aws-free-tier-really-free/. Sorry this isn't a constructive comment directly related to your question!